# Openshift: share MySQL cartrige between applications

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, openshift

I have Java EE web application on RedHat Openshift PaaS, which consists of JBoss EWS, MySQL and phpMyAdmin cartriges. My question is, whether it is possible to share the MySQL cartrige from application one (let's say app1-myname.rhcloud.com) with my second application running under the same OpenShift account (like app2-myname.rhcloud.com)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this KB: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1051-how-do-i-connect-multiple-applications-to-one-database#comment-form

OpenShift does not support direct connectivity to an embedded database on non-scalable applications.  Having said that, there are 2 workarounds today:

1. Connecting to a scalable application's database using the
   hardcoded values since you won't have $OPENSHIFT_DB_* env vars (for
   scalable apps, see
   https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1049-how-does-scaling-work-in-openshift)
2. ssh port forwarding (see
   https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/accessing-an-server-port-running-in-openshift-from-another-openshift-image)